# Fully Connected Pairwise Graphical Models

Tags: machine-learning, markov-random-fields

Can a fully connected, pairwise graphical model estimate an arbitrary joint distribution on N binary variables?

Answer (score 1):

No. Generally, MRFs can represent arbitrary Gibbs distributions (see the [Hammersley-Clifford theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammersley%E2%80%93Clifford_theorem)).  This is broad class but doesn't encompass everything.

The *pairwise* constraint is further limiting.  So far as I can tell, not all MRFs with higher-order potentials can be represented by a pairwise MRF, so it stands to reason that a pairwise MRF cannot represent an arbitrary distribution.

Finally, even if they *could* represent an arbitrary joint distribution, it would be a moot point for MRFs of any reasonable size - exact inference is going to be massively intractable, so you'd be constrained to whatever assumptions your approximation would make.